# state.post es indefinido en Blog with React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Tengo un problema al renderizar la lista de todos los post con React, quiero renderizar una funcion con un mapeo de los `posts` pero me dice que el que es indefinido, a que se debe . utilizé `mapStateToProps` para llamar al array `todos`

mi componente **ListaPost**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect } from 'react-redux';
import {cargaPost} from '../acciones/index';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
class ListaPost extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchPost();
    }
    renderPost () {
        return this.props.posts.map( post => {
            return(<li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
            <span className="text-right">{post.title}</span>
        </li>)
        })
    }
    render() { 
        // const { posts } = this.props;
        // if (!posts) {
        //   return <div>Loading...</div>
        // }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="text-right">
                    <Link
                    to="/posts/new" 
                    >
                    <button 
                    type="button" 
                    className="btn btn-info">
                    Nuevo Post
                    </button>

                    </Link>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.renderPost()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { posts: state.posts.todos }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPost: cargaPost})(ListaPost);
```

mis **acciones**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_POST = 'FETCH_POST';
export const CREAR_POST = 'CREAR_POST';
const URL = 'http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api';
const API_KEY = '1234557';

// ListaPost
export function cargaPost () {
    const solicitud = axios.get(URL)
    .then( res => { console.log(res) })
    return {
        type: FETCH_POST,
        payload: solicitud
    }      
}
```

y el **reducer**

```
import {FETCH_POST} from '../acciones/index';

const estadoInicial = { todos:[], unPost: null }
// PostReducer
export default function(state=estadoInicial, accion) {
    switch(accion.type) {
        case FETCH_POST:
            return {...state, todos: accion.payload.data }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que en la acción `cargaPost, solicitud = axios.get(URL)` regresa una promesa, los valores de la promesa cumplida solo están definidos adentro del `.then()`, pero tu estás regresando afuera de él (puedes consologear solucitud antes del `return` para que veas que es una promesa). Una posible solución sería utilizar `await` para esperar esos valores y luego despacharlos, pero en mi opinión la mejor solución sería utilizar `redux-thunks`, cuyo objetivo es resolver justo ese problema que estás teniendo. Con *thunks* la solución sería de esta manera:

```
function cargaPost () {
   return dispatch => {
     axios.get(URL)
       .then( res => { 
         dispatch({
           type: FETCH_POST,
           payload: solicitud
         })
       })
   }
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos!